# WordPress nginx redirect from non www to ssl www

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Ubuntu 16.04,
Nginx 1.11.6,
php 7.0.8

I know there are several questions regarding this, but I am still having problems.

Also this is not a problem regarding a loop with the admin site, not yet anyway.

I am using a simple 301 redirect that works perfectly in non WordPress sites

```
 ##redirect to www and ssl
 return 301 https-://www.mydomain.com$request_uri;
```

However, this does redirect to ssl but without the www

Also
In **Setting > General > WordPress Address and Site Address** are both set to

```
http-://domain.com
```

If I change them to `http-://www.domain.com` everything works, however I eventually need this to be a multi-site in which case they recommend only using the domain name.

I also have block just for ssl, again all this works as expected in non WordPress site.

```
server {
    listen      x.x.x.x:443 http2;
    server_name www.domain.com;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you must have to rewrite your redirection code.

Prepare your code in following format.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your rules are for apache not nginx